# Pandas To_SQL is giving the DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load the excel file in SQL server using sqlalchemy, to_sql. When i run the code it gives me below error.

```
quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={SQL Server};"
                                 "Server=XYZ;"
                                 "Database=SNOW;"
                                 "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))

data = pd.read_excel(r'I:\ESS_ITRS_STATS_DATA.xlsx')
# rename columns
data = data.rename(columns={'Gateway': 'Gateway',
                            'Severity': 'Severity',
                            'Country': 'Country',
                            'CSIID': 'CSI_ID',
                            'NetProbe': 'NetProbe',
                            'Entity': 'Entity',
                            'Sampler': 'Sampler',
                            'Variable': 'Variable',
                            'Hostname': 'Hostname',
                            'Absolute_path': 'Absolute_path',
                            'Date': 'Date',
                            'Description': 'Description',
                            'InsertedDateTime': 'InsertedDateTime'})
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Gateway','Severity','Country','CSI_ID','NetProbe','Entity','Sampler','Variable','Hostname','Absolute_path','Date','Description','InsertedDateTime'])
df['InsertedDateTime'] = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime())
df = df.fillna(value=0)
df['CSI_ID'] = df['CSI_ID'].astype(str)
table_name='ITRSALERTS_TEMP'
df.to_sql(table_name,engine,index=False,if_exists="append",schema="dbo", chunksize=25,dtype={col_name: NVARCHAR for col_name in df})
```

i am getting the below error

DataError: (pyodbc.DataError) ('22018', "[22018] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '95.89' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")

below is the content from my excel

Gateway Severity    Country CSIID   NetProbe    Entity  Sampler Variable    Hostname    Absolute_path   Date    Description InsertedDateTime

SST_ISSUER01_NAM_PROD   CRITICAL    UNITED STATES   0   XYZ-1   XYZ-H-1 CPU _Total.%processorTime   XYZ-H-1 0   2020-09-20T15:12:35 95.89   2020-09-21 18:12:57

Answer (score 0):

Apparently data type in database and in dataframe do not match: database expects value '95.89' to be numerical and it is sent as a string. You should cast it to appropriate type, maybe round it (depending on database table definition) in the same way you've already done for CSI_ID column:

```
df['Description'] = df['Description'].astype(float)
```